# Having trouble with Boolean. Making a test if an integer is greater/less than another... How to output saying that he/she is right/wrong?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, output

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Boolean {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String zz;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random r1 = new Random();
    Random r2 = new Random();
    Random greatless = new Random();

    int x = r1.nextInt(10) + 1;

    int y = r2.nextInt(10) + 1;

    int z = greatless.nextInt(2) + 1;

    if (z == 2)
    {
         zz = "<";
    }

    else
    {
         zz = ">";
    }

    System.out.println("Is " + x + " " + zz + " " + y + "? (y/n)");
    String ans = keyboard.nextLine();






}
}
```

I don't know what to write after the keyboard input. I want to tell them if they're right or wrong by using the boolean class... so i want an if else after. I guess something like...

```
if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y")
{
   -insert code-
}

else
{
  - insert code-
}
```

Comment: Homework question. What have you tried?

Comment: More to the point, what's the problem?

Comment: He wants us to fill in the `-insert code-` blocks :/

Answer (score 0):

The logic is:

- if x < y, and z == 2 and ans is "y", then it is correct
- if x < y, and z == 2 and ans is "n", then it is incorrect
- if x < y, and z == 1 and ans is "y", then it is incorrect

etc.

Try to accomplish.

Comment: Well, `.equals("y");` and `.equals("n");`.

Comment: I guess that everybody on this planet knows this :). Except for the guy a few minutes ago posting a question about that... Oh, and the guy an hour ago posting a question. And of course the guy yesterday and the one 3 days ago...

Comment: However, I fixed it :)

Comment: Just didn't want to confuse the poster and add to the pile of `==` vs `.equals()` questions.

Answer (score 0):

Nested `if-else` blocks can help you with responding to all the different possibilities. The idea is to break down the checks into steps and identify what should be checked first and what later. Comments should help you follow the flow.

```
// if the test is for ">", and
if (z == 1) {
    // x really is > y and user said yes
    if ((x > y && ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            // Or, x is < y and user said no
            || (x < y && ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
        System.out.println("Yes, you're correct");
    else // user is wrong
        System.out.println("No, you're incorrect");
// if the test is for "<", and
} else {
    // x really is < y and user said yes
    if ((x < y && ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            // Or, x is > y and user said no
            || (x > y && ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
        System.out.println("Yes, you're correct");
    else // user is wrong
        System.out.println("No, you're incorrect");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to make things that complicated or consider lots of combinations of cases.  Declare a `boolean` `correctAnswer` that will be `true` if the correct answer is Yes and `false` if the correct answer is No.  In the block that sets `zz` to "<", set `correctAnswer` to `x < y` since that's the correct answer.  Once the user inputs the answer, you can compare it to `correctAnswer` to see if it's correct.  You don't need to worry about `x` or `y` any more at that point, since you already have figured out what the `correctAnswer` is.  I'll let you work out the rest of the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
String trueAns = (x>y&&z==1)||(x<y&z==2)?"y":"n";

if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase(trueAns)){
    System.out.println("right!");
}else{
    System.out.println("worng!");
}
```